# Javascript: Why svg gets converted into a png with dark background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, png

I have svg images in my page: 
[image]

And I use to convert to png images (and download them): 
https://github.com/CogComp/apelles/blob/master/public/index.html#L370-L390

```
    var mySVG = $("#" + id + " svg")[0];
    var imgId = id + "-img";
    $(document.body).append('<img height="' + mySVG.getBBox().height + '" width="' + mySVG.getBBox().width + '" id="' + imgId + '" style="visibility: hidden; "/>');
    var tgtImage = document.getElementById(imgId);      // Where to draw the result
    var can = document.createElement('canvas'); // Not shown on page
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var loader = new Image;
    loader.width = can.width = tgtImage.width;
    loader.height = can.height = tgtImage.height;
    loader.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(loader, 0, 0, loader.width, loader.height);
        tgtImage.src = can.toDataURL();
    };
    var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(mySVG);
    loader.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
    sleep(500).then(() => {
        var url = tgtImage.src.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
        window.open(url);
    });
```

Here is the output. Why is the output turned dark?

I tried changing the background color but didn't help.
[image]

Here is the link to the page btw: http://nlp.cogcomp.org/

Update: Checking the SVG code I think I have a background:

[image]

Despite having a background, I tried adding a background to the picture, but doesn't seem to help. Here are a couple of variations I have tried:

```
    var svgQ = $("#" + id + " svg");
    var mySVG = svgQ[0];
    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgQ,'rect');
    rect.setAttribute('x',10);
    rect.setAttribute('y',10);
    rect.setAttribute('width',50);
    rect.setAttribute('height',50);
    rect.setAttribute('fill','#EFEFEF');
    mySVG.appendChild(rect);
    // or mySVG.append(rect);
    $("svg").each(function(){
        $(this).css({ fill: '#000' });
        // or $(this).attr("fill", '#000');
        // or $(this).attr("fill", '#000000');
    });
    svgQ.css({ fill: '#000' });
    // or svgQ.attr("fill", '#000');
    // or svgQ.attr("fill", '#000000');
```

Comment: The background on your original page is nothing, so you need a big white rect(-angle) in the background of your other objects.

Comment: You're referring to the svg; right?

Comment: Yes, `<rect ..../>` inside the svg. Place it first to become background object.

Comment: @swatchai I tried a couple of variations. None seem to work. See my update 1 above?

Comment: Actually I think I know what's happening. My conversion only converts svg to png, and not the css.

Comment: Basically when I drop the css links from my page, svg looks just like the png